# Save GoogleSignIn Auth Token to Keychain Swift 4

Tags: swift, google-api, google-signin

Google's Gmail API Documentation for IOS Sucks their GitHub examples aren't updated to swift.

I currently have Google Sign In successfully implemented in my application. However, when the user opens the app I am running `GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signInSilently()` To ensure the user is still signed in.

**I keep getting this error:**

```
Error Domain=com.google.GIDSignIn Code=-4 "(null)"
```

Here is that their documentation says:

```
Indicates there are no auth tokens in the keychain. This error code 
will be returned by *signInSilently* if the user has never signed in 
before with the given scopes, or if they have since signed out.
```

**How do I add the auth token to the keychain so this error does not happen?**

Comment: I believe you need to check `hasAuthInKeychain` and switch between `signIn` and `signInSilently` respectively. See the documentation at https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/api/interface_g_i_d_sign_in

Comment: Their sample code includes Swift versions, for example [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/sign-in?ver=swift).